# What is 'hostoadeL' command on ubuntu server? -- running at 99%cpu

Tags: ubuntu, server

I was alerted by my VPS host this morning that my ubunutu server is running at 99%+ for a while.

Using 'top' I can see the problem is a command called 'hostoadeL'. Does anyone know what this is and more importantly how do I stop it.

I've tried 'kill *pid*' and a reboot but it just starts up again straight after.

I can't find anything on google either.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, you have probably been hacked using a Redis exploit described in a recent post by Salvatore Sanfilippo (the creator of Redis) on his blog: http://www.antirez.com/news/96

Measures:

- Your Redis instance is most likely bound to the `0.0.0.0` IP. Do you really need that? `127.0.0.1` is usually enough for most cases. If you really need outside access, configure your firewall / security group properly.
- Set up a **password**.
- Disable SSH access to the root user (`PermitRootLogin` option).

Comment: Thanks. I ended up rebuilding in the end.